# Python statement not working well in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I want to show and hide HTML elements depends on the content of the data I receive after pressing the button. data will be created after pressing the button (its output of another py file)
but the if statement not working `{% if data == 'empty' %}` its shows the image not the massage i want.

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
<head>
<title>
Analyze your tweets
</title>
</head>
<br>
<br>    
<h1 class="text-light">Analyze Emotions in Your 2020 Tweets &#128526; </h1>
    
<br>
<br>    
<form action="/external/" method="post">
<div class="outter"  aria-label="actionButtons">
   
<div class="inner">


{% csrf_token %}
<label>Enter your @</label>    
<input id="username" type="text" name="param" placeholder="Username" required >
<input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Analyze" onclick="show();">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
 <div class="outter"> 
 <div class="inner">    
<div class="lds-ellipsis" id="load" style="display: none;"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
<div class="outter"> 
{% if data %}
    {% if data == 'empty' %}
                   <h5 style="font-family:Lato; color: azure; font-size: 18;">Sorry the username you looking for is either private or doesn't exist </h5>
    {% endif %}
<div class="inner">

          <h5 style="font-family:Lato; color: azure; font-size: 18;">Here is your result <span style="color:black;">@{{data}}</span></h5>
          <img id="pic" src="{% static 'images/graph.png' %}" width="640" height="480" />


 </div>
{% endif %}
</div>
<br>
<br>    
<div class="outter2">     
    <h5>This website will <u>not</u> violate your Account Privacy.</h5>    
<h6> by Reem & Taif</h6>
 </div>   
    
</html>

<script>
    function show(){
        var r = document.getElementById("username");
        if(r == ""){
        var e = document.getElementById("load");
        e.style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

**I've tried to add else but still not working**

Comment: `its shows the image not the massage i want` horrible disappointment. However you should check what `data` really is in your case.

Comment: the data is output from another py file and its string.

Comment: And what is it in this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

The image is being shown because it's outside of your if check.
You should use

```
{% if data == 'empty' %}
    <h5 style="font-family:Lato; color: azure; font-size: 18;">Sorry the username you looking for is either private or does not exist </h5>

{% else %}
    <div class="inner">
    <h5 style="font-family:Lato; color: azure; font-size: 18;">Here is your result <span style="color:black;">@{{data}}</span></h5>
    <img id="pic" src="{% static 'images/graph.png' %}" width="640" height="480" />
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I am assuming your python code is explicitly sending the string "empty" in case the username was not provided, which would create a but if someone tries to have a username with the value of "empty".
I would accomplish the same goal by checking if the string is empty:

```
{% if data }
    <!--Add normal data display here-->
{% else %}
    <!--Add empty data display here-->
{% endif %}
```

as you almost do just a few lines before.

Comment: I've tried this and still not working ... but if I use your second suggestion then once I run the page the massage will be there and I want to only to show it if I press the button and run the other py file then I check

Comment: this load to show a gif (loader) to indicate that the output is under processing ...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `else` statement

```html
{% if data == 'empty' %}
                   <h5 style="font-family:Lato; color: azure; font-size: 18;">Sorry the username you looking for is either private or doesn't exist </h5>
<div class="inner">
{% else %}
          <h5 style="font-family:Lato; color: azure; font-size: 18;">Here is your result <span style="color:black;">@{{data}}</span></h5>
          <img id="pic" src="{% static 'images/graph.png' %}" width="640" height="480" />

 </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: {% else %} is not needed as that part is already accomplished by the {% if data } statement.